# How to check anaconda's version on mac?

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed `anaconda` a while ago, and I want to know if I need to re-install it to catch up the new updates.

However, i don't know how to check the current version of `anaconda`

In command line, I type `anaconda -V` it gives

```
anaconda Command line client (version 1.2.2)
```

For `anaconda -v` it returns

```
anaconda: error: too few arguments
```

Comment: @jezrael done, not sure if this is what you mean

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `conda -V`

Make sure the "V" is uppercase.

Comment: This is the version of `conda` (the package manager) not `anaconda` (the metapackage).

Answer (score 9):

The answer is a little bit more complex that one could think at the beginning. The main point is you have the package manager, `conda`, and the metapackage, `anaconda`.

Long story short:

`conda info`

to get version information on conda, while

`conda list anaconda$`

to get version of metapackage.

Detailed explanation on this article I've written on the subject:

https://medium.com/@mauridb/how-to-check-your-anaconda-version-c092400c9978

Comment: This is the option that gave me the Anaconda's version. By the way, your page is top on google if you type "get anaconda version"

Answer (score 5):

`conda --version` gives you the version of the conda-package.
`anaconda --version` gives you the version of the anaconda command line client.

If you like to know the version of the installed Anaconda distribution, you can simply run `python --version` witch gives you an output like

```
    Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)
```

Check that your `$PATH` is set to your anaconda installation with `which python` if you just get the version of python.

Comment: This now only says `Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)` Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Try running

`sudo anaconda -V`

which gives output-
`anaconda Command line client (version 1.6.0)`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
conda list | grep anaconda
```

which should give output like

```
anaconda                  5.0.0.1          py36hfb0b618_1
```

I use this command on linux. Guess it should also work on Mac.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  For me, I have nothing returned.  I think what you've done is installed "anaconda" into your current environment and it is showing that version to you.  Honestly, I didn't think that was possible, but I just searched and there is an anaconda package available, which I haven't installed.